# Align divs horizontally, no vertical stacking, in IE7

Tags: css, xhtml, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a fixed container and inside of that is an additional container which houses a number of DIVs based on user choices. I need these additional DIVs to line up horizontally and provide horizontal scrolling (but not vertical scrolling).
Such as this:
[x] [x] [x]

Essentially, my setup looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="second">
      <div class="final"><img src="..." /></div> //Repeat as needed from user
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS breaks down as such:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#second {
  height: 500px;
}
#final {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

This setup works fine in Firefox however it continues to break in IE7. All of the "#final" divs are stacking vertically:
[x]
[x]
[x]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: From what you've provided so far, I would not have expected that to work like you want in FX. I think you need to make the #final display:inline-block;

Comment: Sorry, I forgot some important information initially. Final is displayed as inline-block.

Comment: Forget the display:inline-block, you don't need that AND a float.

Comment: It's not possible to force a browser to scroll horizontally using the method you've described. The #container div would have to automatically have its width altered to being wider than the sum of the .final divs everytime a new one is added. Javascript is what is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems here. For a start:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="second">
       <div class="final"><img src="..." /></div> //Repeat as needed from user
       <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should have a DIV after your floats that remains constant, telling your browser not to float any subsequent elements (clear:both).

And you have several "final" DIVs, so they be in a CSS class, not an ID.

```
.final {
  float: left;
}
```

That should do it!

**Edit:** That will fix your HTML/CSS errors, at least. But I've just noticed that you want the document to scroll right. The only way to do that is to set the width of the #container div to be wider than the sum of all the widths of the .final divs. Otherwise your browser will attempt to push everything "down".

Comment: You might want to read this article. Clear:both is sloppy as a semantic element when it is only used for style. Use CSS to apply that as an :after element, or define the clear:both on "second"

Comment: With that setup I now have two columns of items but all following items are still stacked beneath.

Comment: @Mike, I'm guessing that's because it's hit the width of your browser window. If you want to force it to scroll off the right of the screen, then you'll need some javascript.

Comment: I understand that. That's what I'm trying to do. I have a jQuery script that treats this element (provided it overflows horizontally) as a slideshow-type object. The script for scrolling works fine but the formatting in IE7 isn't working.

Comment: Well I've got the above code working fine in IE7, provided it doesn't reach the browser edge. You must have typed something wrong.

Comment: That's not the complete sheet, just some of what I thought was important (perhaps I was wrong) But you were right on the adjusting the width of the container. I've got it running smooth now. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="second">
      <div class="final"><img src="..." /></div>
      <div class="final"><img src="..." /></div>
      <div class="final"><img src="..." /></div>
      <div class="final"><img src="..." /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#second {
  height: 500px;
}
.final {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Oops. I typoed. Final is a class, not an id. I'll edit the original post.

Comment: try using display:inline for id "second"

Comment: No good. Still getting essentially the same effect. It's a somewhat complex setup, here's the complete CSS [sheet](http://pastebin.com/bQaEh4Ep) for these items